# Загрузка главного изображения сообщества

Tags: android, vkontakte-api, android-vksdk

Как отправить "POST-запрос" с полем photo?

Это поле должно содержать изображение в формате "multipart/form-data" для загрузки фотографии через API "Вконтакте"?

Какую библиотеку лучше всего использовать?

Comment: Чем не подходит родной SDK  под андроид, что приходится самому формировать запросы? Там нет нужного метода? https://vk.com/dev/android_sdk

Comment: Не очень понятно как должен выглядеть этот запрос

Answer (score 0):

Для организации работы с сервером есть любимая многими библиотека [Retrofit](https://square.github.io/retrofit/). Но Retrofit ценен только в том случае, если с сервера приходят структуры данных в JSON или XML, которые для работы нужно парсить.

При передаче туда или обратно бинарных данных Retrofit будет мешать, в этом случае стоит использовать чистый HTTP-клиент, без всяких "обвесов". Берите [OkHttp](http://square.github.io/okhttp/).

В документации к OkHttp есть достаточно примеров, там вы найдете подходящий для вашего случая: https://github.com/square/okhttp/wiki/Recipes